# Присоединить таблицу к самой себе

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Есть таблица employee:

```
id | fio | salary | bossId

id - идентификатор сотрудника
fio - ФИО сотрудника
salary - з/п сотрудника
bossId - идентификатор начальника (у генерального = null)
```

Как правильно сформировать запрос для получения данных

```
ФИО сотрудника | зарплата сотрудника | ФИО начальника | зарплата начальника
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто связываете таблицу саму с собой, давая разные метки.
В данном случае у первого варианта таблицы метка `e`, у второго `eB`

```sql
SELECT e.fio as 'ФИО сотрудника', e.salary as 'зарплата сотрудника',
eB.fio as 'ФИО начальника', eB.salary as 'зарплата начальника'
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee eB ON e.bossId=eB.id;
```